# Change boot order

Tags: boot, mac, boot-order

I've just installed Ubuntu on a Mac, and everything is working just fine. However i installed it using rEFInd, and now it automacially boots up Ubuntu by default. I'd like the option to select the OS manually at boot. Running efirbootmgt from Ubuntu returns this:

```
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Recovery OS
Boot0082* 
BootFFFF*
```

and i'm unsure about which boot order i should chose, since the last two lacks information

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to choose the Mac OS X as the boot.  I would suggest that once you're in the Mac OS X reinstall rEFInd.  That is something I had to do in the past so that rEFInd was the first boot to allow for manual selection.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Ubuntu is compatible with the Mac Startup Manager. You do not need to install rEFInd. Hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> at startup. Continue to hold down the key until the Startup Manager icons appears. To boot Ubuntu, select arrow below the icon labeled "EFI Boot". To make an operating system the default, you need to hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key before making your selection.

If you still wish to use rEFInd, the post a comment and I can give some additional help.

I would not recommend using `efibootmgr`. If you want to select the default operating system to boot from Ubuntu (and/or macOS), then you can do this using rEFInd, but the this will require editing the `refind.conf` file. Post a comment if you need help setting this up.